# Is TRANSFORM library compatible with OpenModelica

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

Transform library was developed with Dymola.
When trying to simulate in OpenModelica I get errors:

```
[12] 12:09:51 Translation Warning
[TRANSFORM.Fluid.Pipes.BaseClasses.PartialDistributedVolume: 12:26-12:31]: Non-array modification '0' for array component, possibly due to missing 'each'.

[13] 12:09:51 Translation Error
[TRANSFORM.Fluid.Pipes.GenericPipe_MultiTransferSurface: 118:3-135:83]: Variable pipe.pipe.flowModel: Cyclically dependent constants or parameters found in scope TRANSFORM.Fluid.Pipes.GenericPipe_MultiTransferSurface$pipe$pipe.FlowModel$pipe$pipe$flowModel: {Re_turb,Re_lam} (ignore with -d=ignoreCycles).

[14] 12:09:51 Translation Error
[TRANSFORM.Fluid.Pipes.GenericPipe_MultiTransferSurface: 118:3-135:83]: Variable pipe.pipe.flowModel: Cyclically dependent constants or parameters found in scope TRANSFORM.Fluid.Pipes.GenericPipe_withWall$pipe.FlowModel$pipe$pipe$flowModel: {Re_turb,Re_lam} (ignore with -d=ignoreCycles).

[15] 12:09:51 Translation Error
[TRANSFORM.Fluid.Pipes.GenericPipe_MultiTransferSurface: 118:3-135:83]: Variable pipe.pipe.flowModel: Cyclically dependent constants or parameters found in scope TRANSFORM.Fluid.ClosureRelations.PressureLoss.Models.DistributedPipe_1D.FlowModel$pipe$pipe$flowModel: {Re_turb,Re_lam} (ignore with -d=ignoreCycles).

[16] 12:09:51 Translation Error
Error occurred while flattening model TRANSFORM.Fluid.Pipes.Examples.GenericPipe_Tests.withWall
```

Is the library compatible with OpenModelica?
If not, what are the steps required to make it compatible?

Comment: Maybe this question is better asked in the TRANSFORM issue tracker? An old ticket about OM exists: https://github.com/ORNL-Modelica/TRANSFORM-Library/issues/61 Maybe it is time to open a new one? Probably contributing to the library with fixes to make it compliant is very welcome!?

Comment: What OpenModelica version are you using? From the error messages I can deduce you are using the old front-end. May I suggest using 1.16, just released and see if it works with that?

Comment: Thanks! I am using the latest release v1.16 with my old  frontend disabled from settings

Comment: I will have a quick look myself and see what I can find out.

Comment: Thanks a lot that would be real help. Some of the packages and models run fine but majority are buggy

Comment: There are quite some issues with the library. Is not really conform to the Modelica specification. Using Dymola pedantic mode a lot of issues are detected. I will start fixing these first but it will take a while. I will open a PR on their repo when I'm done.

Comment: I made a PR, let's see what they decide about it: https://github.com/ORNL-Modelica/TRANSFORM-Library/pull/68

Comment: TRANSFORM is not currently tested with OpenModelica. There have been significant issues with OpenModelica which, as I understand, are in the process of being fixed. Once addressed (new major release perhaps) then there will be more motivation to actively test against OpenModelica as there is a desire to not restrict TRANSFORM to Dymola. (I'm the developer of TRANSFORM). Adrian's pull request has been approved.

Comment: @Priyanka and yes, if others want to contribute, assistance is very much welcome

Answer (score 1):

TRANSFORM has been tested on OpenModelica as of version 1.16.1 and has found that OpenModelica has numerous errors and issues. As OpenModelica improves this may be revisited in the future.